# How to open Appmanifest.xml file in windows phone 8.1 runtime app(not silverlight)?

Tags: push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, manifest

I am doing push notifications in windows phone 8.1. I am trying this from 10 days, but not getting anything.I googled  for this  but i failed. Any one help me out.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b9cd3081-3d89-42e5-b7f6-3de70d991502/device-not-receiving-c-windows-push-notifications-because-channel-url-incompatible?forum=winappswithcsharp

in this link

Set your app's identity values manually
Open your app's AppManifest.xml file in a text editor and set these attributes of the  element using the values shown here.

we have this information. They said i need to put this code in manifest file.  But in my project enivironment manifest file not the xml file. (it is like entering values in the text fields) then how can i add this lines in manifest file. please any one help me. please save me.

Comment: Please help me anyone.

Comment: Actually in silverlight WMAppmanifest.xml file is there.But I am using runtime app not silverlight,so no appmanifest.xml file there.then what should I do .please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just right click on Package.appxmanifest file and click View Code. You will see an xml file that can be manually edited.